# Cast as numeric when field isnumeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, sql-server-2014

I am using a view with a column that contains a varchar which can have a value like `8.60` or `V` or `NULL`.

And I am trying to create a select statement which casts the value as numeric when it is possible or else return the original value.

So I came up with this test query:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC('V') = 1
        THEN cast(round('V', 1) as numeric(4,1))
        ELSE 'V'
    END
    as Value;
```

And I expect it to return `V`, but I am getting an error: `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`
I have tried playing around with `TRY_PARSE` and `TRY_CAST` and with the `round` and `cast` with no success. The error seems to be with the `THEN` clause, because without, it does not throw an error.

How should I write this query?

**SQL version:** Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4019093) - 12.0.5207.0 (X64)

Using: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v12.0.2000.8

Comment: maybe because You are trying to cast 'V' to numeric like in Your example?
cast(round('V', 1) as numeric(4,1)) - always fails

Comment: You can't have an expression return different types. Either convert the number to text or leave null formatting to the client application

Comment: if you're on SQL Server 2014, then use `TRY_CONVERT`. `ISNUMERIC` can, and does, provide wrong information. For example `ISNUMERIC('.')` returns true, however, both `CONVERT(int,'.')` and `CONVERT(decimal(2,1),'.')` will fail.

Comment: @alhugone That is why I put it inside a case, because it should only cast when it is able to cast, hence the isnumeric.
The 'V' repesents an example string value of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case expression cannot return multiple data types. SQL Server has to convert results from all branches to one data type. And according to datatype precedence rules `numeric` has a higher priority than `varchar` so it converts `v` to numeric nevertheless. You could convert the numeric value to varchar though.

Having said that, I discourage using `ISNUMERIC` because it returns true for nonsense values such as `$` and `-`. Use `TRY_CAST` as suggested in the other answer:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN TRY_CAST(v AS NUMERIC(4, 1)) IS NOT NULL THEN
        CAST(CAST(v AS NUMERIC(4, 1)) AS VARCHAR(100)) -- cast will round as well
    ELSE v
END
```

Comment: . . I had thought of this, but converting a string to a number to cast back to a string doesn't seem useful.

Comment: That is the only way you can have `V` and a number inside same column. Other option that I only heard about was to cast to SQL_VARIANT.

Comment: I thought I tried casting the value to a varchar in a TRY_CAST first, but I guess I forgot to cast it in the THEN.

But this solution seems to working as how I want. Thank you.

Comment: You can almost always cast to VARCHAR without TRY!

Answer (score 6):

A `case` expression returns a single value.  That value has a single type.  Your `case` expression is returning both a number and a string.  The number takes precedence, so SQL Server attempts to convert the string to a number.

Hence, your error.

You could fix this by dispensing with the `'V'` and just using `NULL`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC('V') = 1
             THEN cast(round('V', 1) as numeric(4,1))
             ELSE NULL
        END) as Value;
```

Or, more simply:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(numeric(4, 1), 'V')
```

Note:  I assume that you intend `'V'` as a sample string value and not as a column.  If a column, the single quotes are just wrong.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ... Thank you.

Comment: The first query is producing the same error.
The issue with second query is it returning null when it is not convertable.

Comment: @Yingeling . . . The `NULL` is INTENTIONAL, as stated in the first sentence.  You cannot (reasonably) return a value that is both a string and a number.  Your question is unclear on what to do.

Comment: My question was on how to: "create a select statement which casts the value as numeric when it is possible or else return the original value." as stated in the second sentence in my question.